# Query between two NSDate in coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate

I am using `Coredata` in my application.I want a query from my `Message` table where **date1-date2 >= 5** mins.`date1` and `date2` are `NSDate` objects. Any help will be appreciable

Comment: Did you try to type [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date1 - date2 >= 5*60"]; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it but it should work.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ >= %@)", date1, [date2 dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*5]];
```